# Pagination of related entries

Tags: relationships

I am tring to display a list of news items that are related to a particular entry. I might have set it up using categories but this came as a request after the fact and I was using related entries for another purpose so here is what I have.

```
  {exp:switchee variable = "{segment_4}" parse="inward"}
    {case value="#^P(\d+)$#|''|category"}
      {exp:channel:entries channel="teams" url_title="{segment_3}" limit="1" require_entry="yes"} 
        <section id="newsLanding">
          <h2>{title} Team News</a></h3>
          {parents field="rel_newsTeam" orderby="date" limit="1" paginate="bottom"}
            <article>
              <time datetime="{parents:entry_date format="%Y-%m-%d"}">{parents:entry_date format="%F %j, %Y"}</time>
              <h3><a href="{site_url}news/{parents:url_title}">{parents:title}</a>{if parents:cf_newsSource}{if parents:cf_newsSourceLink}<a class="underlined" href="{parents:cf_newsSourceLink}">{/if} ({parents:cf_newsSource}){if parents:cf_newsSourceLink}</a>{/if}{/if}</h3>
              {parents:cf_newsBody:excerpt}
              {if parents:cf_newsBody:has_excerpt}
                <p class="readmore"><a href="{site_url}news/{url_title}">READ MORE</a></p>
              {/if}
            </article>
            {parents:paginate}
              <p>Page {parents:current_page} of {parents:total_pages} pages {parents:pagination_links}</p>
            {/parents:paginate}
          {/parents}
        </section>
      {/exp:channel:entries}
    {/case}
    {case default="yes"}
      {redirect="404"}
    {/case}
  {/exp:switchee}
```

The url pattern goes something like this 
domain.com/news/teams/specific_team

This works fine to show news entries related to the team. As you can see on the parents field I set it to limit 1 to get pagination to kick in and attempted what I thought would be reasonable (parents:paginate) but it just outputs the tag not any actual pagination.

Any ideas on how I could paginate this or is it not possible?

Comment: did you get any solution for `{parents:paginate}`? I am having the same problem.

Comment: sorry never did come up with an answer or solution.